# Python 3 sort settings

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which stores words and their frequencies. I need obtain a sorted list from this dictionary. Words should be sorted in descending order of the number of occurrences in the text, and at the same frequency of occurrence - in lexicographical order. I use this code:

```
for items, quantity in sorted(D.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0), reverse=True):
    print(items, quantity)
```

which produces this output:

```
damme 4
van 3
name 3
is 3
my 2
hi 2
claude 2
bond 2
your 1
what 1
jean 1
james 1
```

Words are correctly sorted in descending order of the number of occurrences in the text, but words with the same number of occurrences are sorted by their reversed lexicographical order. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use `reverse=True`, return *negative* numbers:

```
sorted(D.items(), key=lambda i: (-i[1], i[0]))
```

as `-4` sorts before `-3`. For ties, the forward lexicographical sort for the keys is then used.

Demo:

```
>>> D = {'hi': 2, 'jean': 1, 'bond': 2, 'my': 2, 'what': 1, 'damme': 4, 'van': 3, 'claude': 2, 'name': 3, 'james': 1, 'your': 1, 'is': 3}
>>> for item, quantity in sorted(D.items(), key=lambda i: (-i[1], i[0])):
...     print(item, quantity)
... 
damme 4
is 3
name 3
van 3
bond 2
claude 2
hi 2
my 2
james 1
jean 1
what 1
your 1
```